# Does F# List.Map guarantee the executing order from left item to right item?

Tags: f#, functional-programming, parallel-processing

I have a list of http commands which need to be executed in a particular order.

```
Let cmd = [
    (Get, "http://login.xxx.com"); 
    (Post, "http://login.xxx.com", "login=name;password=pwd");
    ....]

cmd |> List.map (crawl)
```

Will the crawl always run the http requests top-down (even in a multiple core computer)? What's the best way to force the executing order if it cannot be guaranteed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, List.map is single threaded so the order of execution is guaranteed. You just need to ensure your crawl function doesn't lanch asynchonous fire and forget operations, this is probably already the case as it's the simplest way do things, i.e. ensure you use `WebClient.DownloadString` not the async version.

Comment: Will the future version of F# optimize it and make it multiple thread? Especially it's immutable and that's what functional programming is good at.

Comment: Doubtful.  Automatic parallelization is still mostly a pipe dream, except perhaps in limited domains.  However programmer-specified parallelization is often trivial, assuming immutability (e.g. simply change `List.map` to `PSeq.map`, given the right `PSeq` module of parallel operators.)

Comment: List.map does not mutate the input, and its output is immutable, but the function passed to it may have side effects.  Which takes us back to programmer-specified parallelization...

Comment: Just curiously, will haskell guarantee the order then? How to handle it in haskell if not?